# AngularJS ng-click function go to URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Being a newbie to AngularJS and starting a new project Im in need of a solution to why a `ng-click` on a form cancel button isn't redirecting to the view I set up. From what I read in other similar questions here it should work. What could be going wrong?

html

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-cancel" data-ng-click="programEditCancel('/program-details')">
 <i class="fa fa-times"></i> cancel
</button>
```

js

```
configAppControllers.controller('programEditFormCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', function ($scope, $http, $location) {

        $scope.programEditCancel = function (path) {
            $location.path(path);
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: is the button within  `programEditFormCtrl` controller scope? Also, is the route valid in your config?

Comment: try using `alert(path);` to see if you get a valid path

Comment: Yes, that was the problem, I did fix that and it redirects, but instead of going to /program-details it redirects to the default page which is /home

Comment: Yes, the alert finds the correct path

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!! Issue was that because the routes use ID's just trying to go back to #/program-details was not a valid URL I changed the code to 
data-ng-click="programEditCancel('/program-details/:organizationId/:programId')"

and Voila, all is well!

Thanks for helping!